# Находить слова в предложении

Tags: python

У меня есть список из запретных слов
И проблема в том что когда я пишу слово (танк продаю) а у меня в черном списке есть оба слова
то он пропускает это и не выдает как слово которое в чс
А вот если я напишу (танк) и (продаю) по отдельности то все работает
Как можно сделать так чтоб он работал и тогда когда есть оба этих слова

```
list = await db.black_list()
    blacklist = []
    for i in list:
        blacklist.append(i['words'].lower())
    if word.lower() in blacklist:
        await message.answer('Слово в черном списке')
    elif word.lower() not in blacklist:
        ...
```

Comment: то все работает - что работает? покажите ваш код

Comment: @splash58 исправил

Answer (score 1):

Разбейте строку по словам и подчистите их от пробелов и знаков препинания. А потом в цикле проверяйте каждое слово на присутствие в черном списке

```
wlist = list(map(lambda x: x.strip(' \t\n,.'), word.lower().split()))
for x in wlist:
  if x in blacklist:
    await message.answer('Слово в черном списке')
  break
```

Comment: А регуляркой не проще будет в данном случае?

Comment: если добавит чего к функционалу, то да. а так - не знаю

Answer (score 0):

**вариант 1:**

1. разбейте строку на слова через `split()`
2. проверьте все слова на вхождение в ваш чёрный список (список лучше сделать через множество `set` чтобы быстрее искалось)

**вариант 2:**

на случай, если в ЧС находятся и фразы, тогда можно пойти от обратного - проверить все слова и фразы из ЧС на нахождение в вашей строке (через `in`)

Ну и чтоб всё работало в разных вариантах лучше произвести замену пробельных символов (пробелов и табуляций) на один пробел, перевести строку (и строки из ЧС) к нижнему или верхнему регистру

Comment: на счет второго варианта с тем чтоб делать с нижнего или верхнего я сделал, а вот предугадать фразы или словосочетание который придет в голову пользователю невозможно, попробую первый ваш пример

Comment: в варианте 2 я имел в виду, что если у вас в ЧС есть `раз два`, а в строке пользователя есть `и вот раз два мы тут`, то сделав `'раз два' in user_text` вы получите `True`